# How can I use github api to find most recent repositories?

Tags: javascript, git, github

I realize I can use the `since` parameter in my API call to determine which range of repos to download:

```
'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0'
```

But is there a way to only pull the most recently updated repositories?

I checked out https://www.githubarchive.org/ but I could not find an easy to use command line interface associated with it. It seems like the only way to use it is to use Google's SDK. I am trying to get a list of all the most recently updated repos on Github using Node.js.

Comment: How recent is _most recent_? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

API **init**

self = None
assign = Null

'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0'
'https://api.github.com/repositories?since=0'

Comment: please explain the answer, add some description to it